# Ubuntu Server 16.04 no network driver

Tags: networking, drivers, server

Dell PowerEdge sc440 Server

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04 on an old dell server and like a month a go I just upgrade my hard drive.(250GB to 1TB) Everything was running smooth till yesterday when i try to remove some KDE that i didn't use and got my self in this trouble *-network UNCLAIMED... Can someone help me out or give me some ideas how to download and install driver for the network?

NetXtreme BCM5754 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5754 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:167a] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge SC440 [1028:01df]
        Kernel driver in use: tg3
        Kernel modules: tg3
```

This is my first time post...

Comment: Hi Xavier! Please post more info: e.g. `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: I have two of the same server and this is the one thats work purfectly.                                                            lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5754 Gigab                                                it Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:167a] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge SC440 [1028:01df]
        Kernel driver in use: tg3

Comment: The line with Kernel modules is missing! Maybe you forgot it or you have to run the command with 3 lines appended: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` **And** please post the output into your original post!

Comment: read my comment above! **-A3**

Comment: What do you mean in your post by **remove some KDE** ? Did you removed via command line or apt command? (The Kernel driver and modules seems to be ok)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? Thanks.